# What Is Session Border Controller

Tags: firewall, nat, voip

What is Session Border Controller(SBC). And What is the Advantages of SBC. How Does It Works?

Comment: Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 7):

For Cisco ASR Series:

> **SBC Overview**
>
> SBC functions are becoming very popular in the voice-over-IP (VoIP)
>   industry; they are the key components used for interconnecting
>   enterprise and service provider VoIP and multimedia networks.
>
> Because the SBC meets the growing need for secure, IP-centric
>   interconnections between enterprise and service provider networks, a
>   critical need for intelligent border element functions has grown. With
>   the SBC, you can make voice or video calls without worrying about
>   protocols, network reachability, or security of your network. Such
>   elements provide physical and logical ingress and egress demarcations,
>   signaling and media control, consolidated security, and management
>   features. The SBC is in a sense a toolkit of functions such as
>   Signaling Interworking, network hiding, security, quality of service
>   (QoS), and much more.
>
> The SBC facilitates simple and cost-effective connectivity between
>   independent networks. It provides direct IP signaling and media
>   interconnections, thereby lowering cost and performance latencies and
>   improving media quality for multimedia sessions. Additionally, it
>   offers greater flexibility in migrating from traditional time-division
>   multiplexing (TDM) to unified communications services.
>
> **Challenges in Direct VoIP Interconnect**
>
> When a voice call connects from one service provider to another
>   service provider, usually TDM interconnects are used. With the
>   emergence of VoIP technologies, service providers started using IP
>   connectivity to connect to other networks so that calls originating
>   from an IP phone could stay on the packet network from end to end.
>   Service providers then found new challenges in passing VoIP calls to
>   other service providers.
>
> Because VoIP subscribers can have unique environments with respect to
>   protocols, IP addresses, codecs, the way they carry dual tone
>   multifrequency (DTMF) traffic, etc., interconnecting two network
>   domains can be very difficult. In addition, each provider wants to
>   protect its own network from other providers' networks. Furthermore,
>   service providers face other concerns with regard to call detail
>   records (CDRs), billing records, quality of voice calls,
>   troubleshooting, and feature interactions - all of which make
>   end-to-end VoIP performance extremely challenging.
>
> **Role of SBC in VoIP Interconnect**
>
> VoIP, video streaming, instant messaging, multimedia conferencing, and
>   interactive gaming are just some of the real-time, IP-based
>   applications enjoying rapid growth in today's competitive
>   communications market. Service providers are now finding it efficient
>   and economical to directly interconnect their real-time VoIP and
>   multimedia networks to their subscribers as well as to other service
>   provider networks. This trend has created a requirement for SBCs to
>   help service providers control and manage real-time multimedia
>   communications sessions at the borders between their IP networks. In
>   addition, SBCs are also useful for the following requirements:
>
> - Creating proper points of demarcation between service providers, or between enterprises and service providers, for manageability in the
>     rich-media deployments such as VoIP and video
> - Hiding internal network topology from the peering partner or the outside world for security purposes
> - Using the SBC to provide interworking of protocols between H.323 and SIP, or between SIP and SIP (because of the rapidly changing
>     standards and implementation of SIP)
> - Media transcoding, routing VoIP traffic to traverse firewalls, performing Network Address Translation (NAT) and Port Address
>     Translation (PAT), and ensuring QoS
>
> To overcome some challenges, devices such as SBCs are needed at
>   various interconnect points.
>
> SBCs are generally deployed in one of two models: unified and
>   distributed deployment.

Complete Overview:

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/routers/asr-1000-series-aggregation-services-routers/solution_overview_c22-448240.html